# How to inherit a class?

Tags: c#, wpf

I Want to inherit this class

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    string _name;
    string _path;
    long _size;
    byte[] _image;
    public Item(string Name, string path, long Size, byte[] image)
    {
        _name = Name;
        _path = path;
        _size = Size;
        _image = image;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Path
    {
        get { return _path; }
        set { }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public long Size
    {
        get { return _size; }
        set { }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string SizeToString
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_size == 0) return "Folder";
            return CnvrtUnit(_size); 
        }
        set { }
    }
}
```

I tried to inherit it:

```
public class ItemEx : Item
{
    public ImageSource Icon
    {
        get
        {
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(_image))
            {
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bi.StreamSource = ms;
                bi.EndInit();
            }
            return bi;
        }
        set { }
    } 
}
```

then when I assign an instance of `ItemEx` to instance of 'Item', it doesn't work

```
public void Assign(Item item)
{
    ItemEx x = item as ItemEx; //its still null
}
```

Why is this happening? and what should I do to get it work?

**P.S.:** *I need to inherit this class, because it came from WCF service which doesn't pass `ImageSource`, so i passed it as `byte[]` then item has to contain an ImageSource named "Icon" for WPF MVVM purpose.*

Comment: You cannot override a class. You can inherit from a class and override methods, properties, etc.

Comment: He inherited properly but got the terminology wrong.

Comment: yes my fault, how to inherit this class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a perfect solution

```
public class ItemEx : Item
{
public byte[] IconData
    {
        get { return icon; }
        set 
        { 
            icon = value;
            Icon = null;
        }
    }
    public ImageSource Icon
    {
        get { return ToImageSource(IconData); }
        set { RaisePropertyChanged("Icon"); }
    }
}

public static ImageSource ToImageSource(byte[] icon)
    {
        if (icon != null)
        {
            BitmapImage biImg = new BitmapImage();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(icon);
            biImg.BeginInit();
            biImg.StreamSource = ms;
            biImg.EndInit();
            return biImg;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the underlying type of *item* in the line:

```
public void Assign(object item)
```

e.g. what do you see if you run MessageBox.Show(item.GetType()).

If *x* is null after

```
ItemEx x = item as ItemEx; //its still null
```

then *item* isn't of type ItemEx. I assume you're sending an ItemEx from the Client; otherwise it won't work. Also note that _image is private in Item so you won't be able to access it in ItemEx unless you modify the base class.

Do you know why the other three properties of the *'Item'* class are exposed via properties whereas '*image*' is not. This seems to be the problem.

Comment: What's null? Are you saying item is null? item.GetType() can't be null.

Comment: If item was created ("new"ed/constructed) as an Item, it can never be directly assigned to an ItemEx, because it isn't and never was an object of that type. Consider creating a constructor for your ItemEx class which accepts a parameter of type Item, and within it, perform a memberwise assignment to copy across all the values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass byte[] _image to ImageSource like below instead of try to override that class:

```
private static BitmapImage LoadImage(byte[] imageData)
    {
        if (imageData == null || imageData.Length == 0) return null;
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream(imageData))
        {
            mem.Position = 0;
            image.BeginInit();
            image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.UriSource = null;
            image.StreamSource = mem;
            image.EndInit();
        }
        image.Freeze();
        return image;
    }
 Image img = new Image();
 img.Source = LoadImage(Item._image); // for example
```

Comment: I'm actually dealing with ModelView Class for WPF ListView's Items, your solution only works with winforms.

Comment: Why do you say that! "img" is an Image Control in WPF?

Comment: yes its image control in wpf which is bounded to "Icon" property of type "ImageSource"